# Edit Form method Fill (package vform)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I request help me with this situation, I am trying to show a form to edit it but the idrol field returns an object, how can I access it to show me the user's role correctly

```xml
<div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Asignar Rol</label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid': form.errors.has('idrol')}" 
                   v-model="form.idrol"
                   name="idrol">
                  <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione Rol</option>
                  <option v-for="role in arrayRoles" :key="role.id" :value="role.id" v-text="role.name">
                  </option>
            </select>
             <has-error :form="form" field="idrol"></has-error>                                       
      </div>
</div>
```

Without using the fill method, I can access the property as follows
`this.idrol =data['roles'][0].id` it shows the role,
but in this way I would not be taking advantage of the benefits of the vform package

Edit Method

```js
editModal(user) {
    console.log(user);                
    let me = this;        
    me.form.reset();
    me.form.clear();
    me.modal = 1;
    me.tipoAccion = 2;
    me.form.fill(user);                
}
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: can you provide us the package link that you are using?

Comment: this is package https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform

Comment: If you have in idrol some object why you have v-model='form.idrop' ? can you paste the object ?

Comment: `{…}
__ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }​
all_permissions: Array [ {…} ]​
busy: 
​created_at: "2019-04-09 18:30:37"
​dob: "1970-09-09"
​email: "asistente@gmail.com"
first_name: "Maria"
​id: 4
​identity_number: 987451
​idrol: ""
​iduser: ""
​last_name: "Torres"
​roles: (1) […]​​
0: {…}​​​
__ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }​​​
created_at: ​​​
guard_name: ​​​
id: 3​​​
name: "Asistente" `  
this is the response of the USER object

Comment: `export default {
        data(){
            return{                                                
                form: new Form({
                    iduser:         '',
                    idrol:     '',
                    identity_number:'',
                    first_name:'',
                    last_name: '',                
                    dob:  '',
                    phone_number:   '',
                    email:          '',
                    password:       '',                    
                }),                               
            }
        }},`

Comment: My Controller `public function index(Request $request)
{ 
   $name = $request->get('name'); 
   $users = User::search($name)->with('roles')->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10); return [
     'pagination' => [
      'total'        => $users->total(),
      'current_page' => $users->currentPage(),
      'per_page'     => $users->perPage(),
      'last_page'    => $users->lastPage(),
      'from'         => $users->firstItem(),
       'to'           => $users->lastItem(),
                ],'users' => $users            
            ];
    }`